# Partion Equal Subset Sum Leetcode : RUNTIME ERROR

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

```
class Solution {
public:

bool subsetSum(vector<int> a,int n,int sum){
    bool dp[n+1][sum+1];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=sum;j++){
            if(j==0){
                dp[i][j]=true;
            }
            else if(j==0){
                dp[i][j]=false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=sum;j++){
            if(j < a[i-1]){
                dp[i][j]= dp[i-1][j];
            }
            else{
                dp[i][j]= dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-a[i]];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[n][sum];
}

bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums) {
    int i,n=nums.size();
    int sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum+=nums[i];
    }
    if(sum%2!=0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return subsetSum(nums,n,sum/2);
    }
}
};
```

We have to return TRUE or FALSE whether it is possible to partition the given array into 2 parts but there sum must be same (size may vary).
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:32:45 getting this error, please help.

Comment: Apart from using non-standard VLAs in your code you are also not initializing all elements (you are only initializing `dp[i][0]` so reading values other than that invokes UB

Comment: I have difficulty to understand `else i(j ==0)`. Maybe `i==0`

Comment: You know about vectors, so why use variable-length arrays? They are both non-standard and easiy cause stack overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it just has to be a vector or array bounds error. So looking closer what do we see?

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    ...
         dp[i][j]= dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-a[i]];
                                           ^^^^
```

`a` has size `n` therefore, when `i` equals `n`, `a[i]` is a vector out of bounds error.

Being able to see clearly the code you have written is a useful skill for a programmer to have. Try to be objective when looking at your own code, try to discard the assumptions you have.

Answer (score -1):

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683296/6553328) clearly explains the issue.
- All dynamic programming solutions are already explained [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/solution/).

#### Alternative Solution

Since the max number and max length are very limited, we can also use `std::bitset` for solving this problem (along with proper variable naming):

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

#define MAX_NUM 100
#define MAX_LEN 200

using ValueType = std::int_fast16_t;

static const struct Solution {
    static const bool canPartition(std::vector<int>& nums) {
        std::bitset<MAX_NUM * MAX_LEN / 2 + 1> bits(1);
        ValueType sum = 0;

        for (const auto& num : nums) {
            sum += num;
            bits |= bits << num;
        }

        return !(sum & 1) && bits[sum >> 1];
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Considering you posted an entirely different solution, this looks an awful lot like a link-only answer. The only thing here that directly answers the question is your first bullet. Please read [answer]. Posting your own solution isn't generally appropriate here; SO is about helping people learn how to solve _their_ problems, not showcasing _your_ code.

Comment: Yes, answers are supposed to help future readers. But they still have to answer the question. As far as I'm concerned, this answer doesn't do that. "what does this post do, if not helping?"—dumping code and saying "this completely different code works, read it and figure it out" isn't very helpful. The other answer here specifically identifies a potential problem with _OP's_ code, explains the problem, and points towards a solution. That is much more appropriate.

Comment: You mean the title that specifically says it's about _a runtime error with the code OP shared in the body of the question?_

Comment: Well, that's what SO is about: helping people learn, which usually means you'll need to do some explaining. If you just want to showcase your own code, please do it elsewhere.